# Write this.props.element beside a HTML tag in JSX

Tags: reactjs

How can I write this.props.element beside a HTML tag in JSX of react.js ?

```
? this.props.element (<span className="edit" onClick={()=> {this.props.makeInputBox(this.props.item)}}>Edit</span>):
```

I getting below error

`TypeError: this.props.element is not a function`

Comment: But what is `this.props.element`? :)

Comment: Thanks @YuryTarabanko. It is a value passed from Parent component.

Comment: Well, you didn't answer the question. Your code expects it to be a function. But according to the error message the Parent component passes something different.  It is not clear how do you expect it to work and what is your question actually about.

Comment: Thanks @YuryTarabanko. Actually I would like to write `this.props.element <span></span>`. `this.props.element` contains a String Name. How can I write that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to show the constant data or props data in the jsx, you need to add that in curly braces. And in your case, you need to enclose the this.props.element and  tag in some parent element like:

```
? <div>{this.props.element} <span className="edit" onClick={()=> {this.props.makeInputBox(this.props.item)}}>Edit</span></div>:
```

Comment: Thanks @Hitesh Chaudhari. Your solution is working. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help @abuabu

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the content within another span and write it like

```
? <span>{this.props.element} <span className="edit" onClick={()=> {this.props.makeInputBox(this.props.item)}}>Edit</span> </span>:
```

Answer (score 0):

? {this.props.element}  {this.props.makeInputBox(this.props.item)}}>Edit